# LaTeX math equation same font size

Tags: math-mode, fonts, equations

I am trying to replicate following equation in LaTeX. As you can see the font size of numbers is exactly same for all numbers in this equation.

[image]

When I type in LaTeX:

```
$$\frac{\left(5 \frac{4}{45}-4 \frac{1}{6}\right)\div 5 \frac{8}{15}}{\left(4 \frac{2}{3}+0.75\right) \times 3 \frac{9}{13}}\div 34 \frac{2}{7}+\frac{0.3\div 0.01}{70}+\frac{2}{7}$$
```

I am getting following equation:

[image]

As you can see the font for fractions is smaller (eg: 4/45; 1/6). Is it possible to have same font for whole number as well as numbers in fractions.

Comment: For the ‘inner’ fractions, you can use the amsmath `\dfrac` command.

Comment: Thank you @Bernard your solution worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look:

```
\dfrac{\left(5 \dfrac{4}{45}-4 \dfrac{1}{6}\right)\div 5 \dfrac{8}{15}}{\left(4 \dfrac{2}{3}+0.75\right) \times 3 \dfrac{9}{13}}\div 34 \dfrac{2}{7}+\dfrac{0.3\div 0.01}{70}+\dfrac{2}{7}
```

Just change frac by dfrac:

[image]

Comment: As suggested @Bernard in his comment ... at least you should provide complete MWE-

Comment: Sorry @Bernard, I did not show the comments. Not the best layout on my phone...